# Computer freezing and monitor going off

Tags: windows, drivers, freeze

Recently I've experienced lots of freezing occurrences in my PC. I've opened Task Manager, but it doesn't show any high load on the CPU.
Lately my monitor suddenly went off after short intervals of a few seconds. I tried using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to reset my graphics card, but to no avail.

Then it directed me to the blue screen of death with the message string

> SYNTHETIC_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT

Does this automatically mean a hardware problem?

Comment: If Windows, go to Reliability Monitor and see what errors are there. Again if Windows, set Advanced System Properties to produce Mini Dumps and review these with Nirsoft Blue Screen View.

Comment: also check Event Viewer